# Simplecov report by test type

Tags: ruby, testing, code-coverage

I have two sets of tests in a Ruby project:

```
test:unit
test:functional
```

When i use Simplecov to generate coverage reports, the report generated by test:unit gets overridden by the report generated by test:acceptance.

Is it possible to configure Simplecov to generate reports in two separate directories like coverage-unit and coverage-acceptance?